# Prove that $f(\alpha)$ is differentiable using uniform convergence.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

Please help me to handle the following problem:

> Prove that if $\alpha>0$, then $$f(\alpha)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x}{x^{\alpha+2}+1}dx$$
>
> is differentiable.

My attempt:

I am going to use the following fact:

If $f(x,\alpha)$ and $f'_{\alpha}(x,\alpha)$ are continuous in $[0,+\infty)\times(0, +\infty)]$ and

1. $I(\alpha)=\int_0^{+\infty}f(x,\alpha)$ is convergent
2. $\int_0^{+\infty}f'_{\alpha}(x,\alpha)$ is convergent uniformly for $\alpha \in (0,+\infty)$

then for any $\alpha \in (0,+\infty)$ there exists $I'(\alpha)=\int_0^{+\infty}f'_{\alpha}(x,\alpha)$

In my notes this is called *Leibniz rule*, but I do not know standard name of this result in English. Please let me know.

In fact this result was mentioned in a bit more general settings, but I put constants (integration limits) related to the problem.

We have  $f'_{\alpha}(x,\alpha)=-\frac{x^{\alpha+3}\log x}{(x^{\alpha+2}+1)^2}$. So $f(x,\alpha)$ is continuous $[0,+\infty)\times(0, +\infty)]$, but $f'_{\alpha}(x,\alpha)$ is **not**, because it is not defined when $x=0$. **How should I handle this issue?**

$$f(\alpha)=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x}{x^{\alpha+2}+1}dx < \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x}{x^{\alpha+2}}dx=\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\alpha+1}}dx<+\infty$$
This is well know fact.

Now I have to prove that that $$f'_{\alpha}(x,\alpha)=-\frac{x^{\alpha+3}\log x}{(x^{\alpha+2}+1)^2}$$ converges uniformly. If there were no $\log x$ factor, that would be easy, but it is not the case. **How should I prove uniform convergence?**

Thanks a lot for your answers and for pointing on my mistakes.

Comment: $\displaystyle f(\alpha)=\frac{\pi}{(\alpha+2)\sin\frac{2\pi}{\alpha+2}}$, btw. The $\log x$ factor is not an issue, because $|\log x|=O(x^\epsilon)$ for every $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you obtained that result?

Comment: Using the substitution $x\to\exp(t/(\alpha+2))$, and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2596907/evaluating-a-real-integral-using-complex-analysis/2597404#2597404).